# androidx getFragmentManager() has been deprecated

Tags: android, android-fragments, androidx, fragmentmanager, deprecation-warning

Getting deprecation warnings for `androidx.fragment.app.Fragment`:

> warning: [deprecation] `getFragmentManager()` in `Fragment` has been deprecated.

What to do?

Answer (score 18):

The sources of version `1.2.0` explain it in more detail:

> This has been removed in favor of `getParentFragmentManager()`, which
>   throws an `IllegalStateException` if the `FragmentManager` is `null`. Check if
>   `isAdded()` returns `false` to determine if the `FragmentManager` is `null`.

Comment: It is explicitly mentioned in [the Javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/fragment/app/Fragment.html#getFragmentManager()), no need to look at the source.

Comment: In short, you should use `getParentFragmentManager()` instead of `getFragmentManager()` or `requireFragmentManager()` since both got deprecated in `androidx.fragment.app.Fragement`

Comment: The name is confusing. I want the manager of the current fragment and not of it's parent. Google's changed code looks like the only point is the change itself...

Answer (score 6):

In Kotlin:
`fragmentManager`, `requireFragmentManager()` are deprecated. 
Current way: **parentFragmentManager**

In JAVA:
`getFragmentManager()`, `requireFragmentManager()` are deprecated. 
Current way: **getParentFragmentManager()**

Answer (score 1):

**Deprecation of getFragmentManager():**

> The getFragmentManager() and requireFragmentManager() methods on
>   Fragment have been deprecated and replaced with a single
>   getParentFragmentManager() method, which returns the non-null
>   FragmentManager the Fragment is added to (you can use isAdded() to
>   determine if it is safe to call).

[Use Google Docs for more reference](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/fragment)